# what happened and why? moved file to wildcard, now cannot find moved file, contents of new location has missing files

Tags: bash, mv

Sleepy me this morning moved folder from location A to B

I was currently in the directory of B and instead of using `.` i used an `*`

```
mv /home/user/temp/ *
```

Before doing this, directory B had 4 folders and a file.

Now directory B has one folder.

What did I accidentally do? I need more coffee and is there a way that I can undo this mistake?

Comment: Go into the location, where you've done `mv /home/user/temp *`, and execute `cd *`. This command will change your current directory with the desired directory, where your files were moved. Usually it is the first (not hidden) sub directory.

Comment: You probably need less coffee or more sleep :) What was the contents of directory B?

Comment: Great found everything in the directory that was still there. Is this by design? Or was that directory randomly chosen? Contents are a project that I am working upon. I have a back up. Sleep or more coffee... both are a plus. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news for you !!

All your files and directories are on the only existing directory under `B/`, including the source directory `/home/user/temp/`.

How this happened:

- When you did `mv /home/user/temp/ *` while at `B/`, the shell expands `*` to all files and directories on the `B/` directory; this happened first, before `mv` is run
- Luckily, the directory came at last according to the collation order on pathname expansion, so the `mv` command became e.g.:

  ```
  mv /home/user/temp/ B/file1 B/file2 B/some_directory
  ```
- As the last argument was a directory, `mv` moved all files and directories into that directory. If the last one were a file, `mv` would have shown an error that the target is not a directory (as there are multiple sources involved).